# Center a tags inside a div nav bar

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating this navigation bar, but I have some trouble aligning my items, the page will also have some *svg* icons in this nav bar later on. But I'm trying to align it like this, but how?

This is probably something very easy to fix, but I've tried to vertical align, and other stuff, but it doesn't move where I want to to move.

[image]

```css
/*
 Navigation
*/

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
}

.topnav button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #0f1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}

.floatRight {
    float: right;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grundfos Metrics</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/site.scss">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/toggletheme.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="floatLeft"            href="#news"><h1>Website Title</h1></a>
            <a class="floatRight"           href="#contact">Coverage</a>
            <a class="floatRight"           href="#news">Archives</a>
            <a class="active floatRight"    href="#home">Home</a>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove all floats and build this with flexbox, this will make your life much easier.

Comment: Remember that  h1 comes with default margin in HTML. Override it by setting the margin to 0px. But I agree with cloned. Should be easier with flexbox

Comment: You should learn ```flex```  it makes it so much easier to make these kind of things.
If you want to I can make your navbar using flex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use flexbox to do that.

Just add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the `.topnav`.

And to align your content left or right, you could use **two container** and a `justify-content: space-between;` on the `.topnav`.

That will have as effect to align the **first container to the most left** and the second to the most right.

But if you **add another container**, **the middle on will be in the middle !** And the two other will be at the same place as before

Aligning the right part with flex will also have as effect to **reverse the order of the elements** ! So don't forget to change that too.

I've done an example for your navbar, don't hesitate to ask if you doesn't understand my solution.

```css
/*
 Navigation
*/

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #0f1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grundfos Metrics</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/site.scss">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/toggletheme.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
          <div class="leftpart">
                      <a href="#news"><h1>Website Title</h1></a>
          </div>
          <div class="rightpart">
                      <a href="#contact">Coverage</a>
              <a href="#news">Archives</a>
              <a class="active"    href="#home">Home</a>
          </div>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #0f1;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
            <div>
                <a href="#news">
                    <h1>Website Title</h1>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">Archives</a>
                <a href="#contact">Coverage</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

In this case, you need to use flexbox first you remove all the float CSS and its class then use flexbox to use two different divs to the first logo and second links.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css.

```
.topnav a {
line-height:17px;
}
```